# Creating combobox in different rows on button click..inside gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to create combobox inside gridview on button click event...
each time when i cklick on button a combobox will be created in the next row ..means every time only row will change column will remains same...

```
private void Buttton_Click(object sender, Event e)
{

   DataGridViewComboBoxCell CellColumn1, CellColumn2, CellColumn3;
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "Column1");
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col2", "sanjeev");

   //make row 1 at all columns into combobox cell
   dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

   CellColumn1 = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0];
   CellColumn2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1];

   j++;
}
```

i tried this logic ..this will create combox inside gridview only at first button click but when i click the button again this is not working..

can any one help me out....

Comment: are you binding grid on your button click??add code for binding gridview on button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer...

private void BTN_ADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  int j=0;

```
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell ColumnItem2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();  // create a combobox cell
            ColumnItem2.ValueMember = "Display";
            ColumnItem2.DisplayMember = "Display";

          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)// it will add elements to a combox
           {
               ColumnItem2.Items.Add(i);
               }

      dataGridView1.Rows.Add();  // add row everytime to add a new combobox to the next row.


         int columncount = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;// count no of coloumns
         int rowcount = dataGridView1.RowCount;;// count no of rows
```

//i kept count no of columns and rows so that by rows and columns count u can specify to which row or  you want to add combobox inside gridview
// below i hard coded the combobox row and column to 2,2 so it will add a combobox to 2nd row and 2nd column.

```
           dataGridView1[2, 2] = ColumnItem2;
         //dataGridView1[2, j] = ColumnItem2;
```

// general way of adding combox to second column and row is everytime added by one as i m incrementing j value every time to each time on button click it will add combox on next row on second column..same way you can specify row and column as per your need.

j++;

}

hope this will help others....

http://csharpprobsandsoln.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-add-combobox-dynamically-to.html